# In Tally ERP9 response xml

Tags: vb6, tally

While send xml to tally to fetch any information from tally into VB then response xml only showing that TallyPrime Server is Running. Response is same while xml has changed or pause / timed is inserted before EXRes receive response from tally.

```
Public Sub LdrEx()
Dim ExCd As String
ExCd = LedXmCd()
Dim objXML As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Set objXML = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
objXML.Open "POST", "http://localhost:9000", False
objXML.send ExCd
Dim EXRes As String
EXRes = objXML.responseXML
Set objXML = Nothing
Dim TFile As String
TFile = Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\Desktop\LdReceived.xml"
  Open TFile For Output As #1
   Print #1, EXRes
  Close #1
End Sub
```

**XML from LedXmCd() is:**

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
    <ID>Voucher Register</ID>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <DESC>
    <STATICVARIABLES>
    <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">20210101</SVFROMDATE>
    <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">20210101</SVTODATE>
    <VOUCHERTYPENAME TYPE="STRING">Receipt</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
    </STATICVARIABLES>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: That's not VB.NET, so I changed the tag to VB6 for you - if it should be VBA instead, please change it.

Comment: Try using `EXRes = objXML.ResponseText`. JFYI, the `ResponseXml` is an `DOMDocument` object not a `String` and the present code is retrieving its `Xml` default property. Unfortunately this handy `DOMDocument` instance is automatically initialized only if the response is signalling `application/xml` for content-type.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether XML is saved in variable ExCd by adding watch and adding breakpoint at

```
objXML.send ExCd
```